# How to check if data exist?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

Firebase rules configuration:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Firebase database data sample

[image]

Using this [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24826338/1460189), I came up with something as below but not working.

```
const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

console.log(currentUser.uid);
  
firebase.database().
ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/userSettings`)
.child({ userSetting_DisplayName, userSetting_City, userSetting_DailyLimit })
.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    console.log('exist');
  }else{
    console.log('not exist');
  }
});
```

which part could've gone wrong?

Comment: I think this line: _`.child({ userSetting_DisplayName, userSetting_City, userSetting_DailyLimit })`_ because i doubt you can use an object as a child

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39236689/3332734 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44852086/3332734

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
firebase.database().
ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/userSettings`)
.once('value', function(snapshot) {
if (snapshot.exists()) {
console.log('exist');
}else{
console.log('not exist');
  }
});
```

then you will be able to check if data exists under `userSettings`

or if you want to check if a particular child has a certain data, then you can do this:

```
ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/userSettings`).orderByChild("userSetting_city").equalTo(valuehere).once(...
```

or if you want check if a particular child is there:

```
ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/userSettings`).child("userSetting_DisplayName").once(...
```

Also from the docs:

> `child`
>
> `child(path)` returns firebase.database.Reference
>
> Gets a Reference for the location at the specified relative path.
>
> The relative path can either be a simple child name (for example, "ada") or a deeper slash-separated path (for example, "ada/name/first").

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#child

Also the child is used to go through a path and all these children are in the same level, so it won't work.